Correcting applying a spirograph code
I use the following code to draw spirograph patterns. I defined 8 colours, but only the last 4 colours are displayed. What is wrong with my application of the code?
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
%=begin spirosegment setting with nRotations and filling=
\newif\ifspiroclosed
\tikzset{pics/spirosegment/.style={code={
\tikzset{spirosegment/.cd,#1}
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spirosegment/##1}} 
\pgfmathparse{(int(1/\pv{dx}+1)}
\tikzset{spirosegment/samples=\pgfmathresult}
\draw[trig format=rad,pic actions] 
plot[variable=\t,domain=(\pv{xmin}-0.002:\pv{xmax}+0.002)*\pv{nRotations}, samples=\pv{samples}, smooth]
(
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*cos(\t)+\pv{p}*cos((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})},
 {(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*sin(\t)+\pv{p}*sin((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})}
)
\ifspiroclosed
 -- ({(\pv{xmax}+\pv{xmin})/2}:\pv{rmin}) -- cycle
\fi;
}},
spirosegment/.cd,R/.initial=6,r/.initial=-1.5,p/.initial=1, dx/.initial=0.01,samples/.initial=21,nRotations/.initial=1,domain/.code args={#1:#2}{%
\pgfmathparse{#1}\tikzset{spirosegment/xmin/.expanded=\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathparse{#2}\tikzset{spirosegment/xmax/.expanded=\pgfmathresult}},
xmin/.initial=0,xmax/.initial=2*pi,closed/.is if=spiroclosed,closed=false,rmin/.initial=1}

\tikzset{nfill/.code={%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myind}{Mod(#1,dim({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro colors}}))}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro colors}}[\myind]}
\tikzset{fill=\mycolor,fill opacity=0.5,draw=\mycolor}
},spiro colors/.initial={"green!60!black","cyan","orange","blue"}}
%=end spirosegment setting with nRotations and filling=
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.6mm, line cap=round, scale=.46, transform shape,spirosegment/.cd,R=6,r=-1.5,p=1,dx=0.5]
\path 
foreach \scl [count=\Y starting from 0] in {1.5, 1.25, 1.04, 0.86, 0.71, 0.58, 0.46, 0.37}
{
foreach \rot [count=\Y starting from 0] in {0,1,2}
{
foreach \clr [count=\Y starting from 0] in {blue,red,green,brown,cyan,purple,orange,violet}
{
(0,0)pic[scale=\scl,draw=\clr,fill=\clr!40,rotate=360/4/8*\rot]{spirosegment={domain={-pi/11+\Y*pi/2}:{pi/11+\Y*pi/2}}}
}}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



It's easy to see when you comment out or remove some colors in the innermost loop: because each pattern is drawn at a multiple of 90deg, the last ones overdraw the first ones.

@MS-SPO So, how can I display the 8 colours?

Depends on your objective, how it shall look like. E.g. a) switch to a 45deg rhythm, b) for a given angle make even rows/lines in color1, odd in color2 etc.

@MS-SPO I want it to look like this; but in 8 colours each repeated 3 times; instead of 4 colours, each repeated 6 times. Or as you suggested even rows/lines in color1, odd in color2 etc.
https://i.sstatic.net/TrPx5fJj.png

Your pic has to be rotated to the right angle, depending on two counters.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  %=begin spirosegment setting with nRotations and filling=
  \newif\ifspiroclosed
  \tikzset{pics/spirosegment/.style={code={
        \tikzset{spirosegment/.cd,#1}
        \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spirosegment/##1}} 
        \pgfmathparse{(int(1/\pv{dx}+1)}
        \tikzset{spirosegment/samples=\pgfmathresult}
        \draw[trig format=rad,pic actions] 
        plot[variable=\t,domain=(\pv{xmin}-0.002:\pv{xmax}+0.002)*\pv{nRotations}, samples=\pv{samples}, smooth]
        (
        {(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*cos(\t)+\pv{p}*cos((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})},
        {(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*sin(\t)+\pv{p}*sin((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})}
        )
        \ifspiroclosed
        -- ({(\pv{xmax}+\pv{xmin})/2}:\pv{rmin}) -- cycle
        \fi;
    }},
    spirosegment/.cd,R/.initial=6,r/.initial=-1.5,p/.initial=1, dx/.initial=0.01,samples/.initial=21,nRotations/.initial=1,domain/.code args={#1:#2}{%
      \pgfmathparse{#1}\tikzset{spirosegment/xmin/.expanded=\pgfmathresult}
      \pgfmathparse{#2}\tikzset{spirosegment/xmax/.expanded=\pgfmathresult}},
    xmin/.initial=0,xmax/.initial=2*pi,closed/.is if=spiroclosed,closed=false,rmin/.initial=1}
  
  \tikzset{nfill/.code={%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myind}{Mod(#1,dim({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro colors}}))}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro colors}}[\myind]}
      \tikzset{fill=\mycolor,fill opacity=0.5,draw=\mycolor}
    },spiro colors/.initial={"green!60!black","cyan","orange","blue"}}
  %=end spirosegment setting with nRotations and filling=
  %
  \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.6mm, line cap=round, scale=.46, transform shape,spirosegment/.cd,R=6,r=-1.5,p=1,dx=0.5]
    \path 
    foreach \scl [count=\X starting from 0] in {1.5, 1.25, 1.04, 0.86, 0.71, 0.58, 0.46, 0.37}
    {
      foreach \rot [count=\Y starting from 0] in {0,1,2}
      {
        foreach \clr [count=\Z starting from 0] in {blue,red,green,brown,cyan,purple,orange,violet}
        {
          (0,0)pic[scale=\scl,draw=\clr,fill=\clr!40,rotate=360/3/8*(\Z*3+\Y)]{spirosegment={domain={-2*pi/19}:{2*pi/19}}}
    }}}
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you very much. Just one more request, if you allow me. Can each even row be rotated halfway; for the peaks to be between the junctions of the colours of the previous odd row?
